# Regular expression for filter c comments

Tags: c, regex

For a merge with a tool I need to compare only non-commented parts of source lines.

So I try to create a filter which detects actual code, i.e. a regular expression that matches all text *EXCEPT* comments.

Perhaps something like this:

```
^.*(?!((/\**([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)|(//.*)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This one will do :

```
(/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)|(//.*)
```

Source : http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html.

Or using non-greedy matching : `(/\*([\r\n]|.)*?\*/)|(//.*)`.

Comment: That does not help. I need to exclude comments.

Comment: @LmaBach can't you strip them before comparing the files ?

Comment: no because i need to ignore the comments only in the merge view. But in the result i want the comments back.

Answer (score 0):

Amine's answer is right, but you could also find for any comments and remove them from the string:

This regex will give you all comments:

```
(/\*.*?\*/)|//.*?\n
```

This will replace the matches with "" (if you're using c++):

```
std::string str2 = std::tr1::regex_replace(string, regex, "");
```

Comment: Do STL regexes not care about multiline strings ?

Comment: I need the negation of "finding all comments" with one expression.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your compiler can help. Some might have an option to preprocess source and strip comments. Maybe the preprocessor can be made to **only** strip comments. This would be the Unix way of having one tool do one thing right--the C preprocessor knows what a comment is (while regexen are a kluge for parsing, IMNSHO).

As a second option, writing a lexer with `lex` or `flex` to recognize comments is easy. There should be plenty of examples on the 'net. Any search engine will turn up tons of hits.

Comment: I use a keil C51 compiler which has not this possiblity. Either i could write a programm which remove comments before merging. But this creates more problems than it solves, because I dont want to loose the comments in the merge result.

Answer (score 0):

For multiline comments use :

`/\/\*([\s\S]*?)\*\//mg`

and for matching single line comments:

`/\/\/([\s\S]*?)[\n\r]?$/mg`

or combine these two for matching all comments
`/(\/\*(?<multiline>[\s\S]*?)\*\/)|(\/\/(?<singleline>[\s\S]*?)[\n\r]?$)/mg`